# Row is fixed at the first row when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can somebody help me?
I want to make a table with mysql data.

the table looks like this

```
|    Name    | Problem |     Action     |
| Ramon Pena |  Dengue | (Assist)(Done) |
```

When you click the assist button, it will become the first row in the table even if you add another row. Is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using plain javascript, or are you open to using the jQuery library? Can you provide a bigger example/sample of what you want to do? It would be helpful if you create a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ with some sample code.

Comment: it is just an idea.
all i want is to make a table that will show a staff and doctor interactions. wherein the staff will be the one that will add rows. and the doctor will be the one that will do the action.
if he click the assist, that row will be at the first row even if the staff is still adding rows.

it was like a queuing system that show the row that is being assist.

Comment: this site is to help with code, not writing it for you. If it is still just an idea, then start writing some code and come back for help if you get stuck.

Comment: im just asking if it is possible to do.
im not asking anyone to do it for me. Sorry.

Comment: yes, this would be possible to do.